# Using maven profile inside eclipse - Resource Stream NPE

Tags: java, maven, properties, nullpointerexception, null

I am trying to use mavens profiles to differentiate between my dev and production accounts - so far i have the following two profiles declared in my pom.xml file

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the openshift profile will be used when invoking 
            mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
            will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the deployments 
            folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/PROD/</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
            <finalName>TomcatHotOrNot</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>TomcatHotOrNot</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
<profile>
        <id>openshift-dev</id>
        <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/DEV/</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
            <finalName>TomcatHotOrNot</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>TomcatHotOrNot</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This means that it should point to the dev / prod properties files depending on which i choose in the eclipse menu. To point to the profile i created I have done the following;

right click the pom.xml -> select maven profile -> chosen/ ticked openshift-dev

In my code i then try and load the properties file like this;

```
String resourceName = "connection.properties";
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Properties props = new Properties();
try(InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
    props.load(resourceStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.error("Unable to load resources file", e);
}
```

The issue I am facing is that a null pointer exception is thrown because resource stream is null. What configurations am i missing to ensure that the properties file can be loaded correctly by eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: maven builder won't respect maven's build profile

Comment: please could you elaborate so i have a chance of finding a solution?

Comment: ok how do you build your project in eclipse ?

Comment: Normally I just write a main method and initiate via a run configuration

Comment: so you rely on eclipse's default builder (if you have build automatically checked) that doesn't respect mavens build profile, you can add directory as source directory and configure where properties file is placed so it will remain limited to eclipse env (i.e. dev env) and it will be available as well